# Error in Postman 500 Internal server error api

Tags: python, json, api, flask, postman

i'm building an api using flask for a web
i already have a database and the GET request works but when i try POST it gives me This error

> 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

This is the code i wrote

```
#User_schema
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
 class Mata:
  fields = ('id', 'name', 'Email', 'Pass', 'Phone', 'Department', 'Major')

#init_schema
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

#create user
@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_User():
 #id = request.json['id']
 name = request.json['name']
 Email = request.json['Email']
 Pass = request.json['Pass']
 #Phone = request.json['Phone']
 Department = request.json['Department']
 Major = request.json['Major']

 new_user = User(name, Email, Pass, Department, Major)
 db.session.add(new_user)
 db.session.commit()

 return user_schema.jsonify(new_user)
```

this is the request i added on post man

```
{
    "name": "User 1",
    "Email": "User1@.com",
    "Pass": "qq1",
    "Phone": "0551",
    "Department": "IT 1",
    "Major": "IT 1"
}
```

i'm also using a local server
i looked at other links and everyone is asking for the logs and if i'm not wrong i think i get them from

> View > Developer > Show DevTools > Console

and this is a screenshot of the log: (i think)

[image]

what exactly is the problem here i don't get it

EDIT: Here is the full code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATION'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class User (db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
 name = db.Column(db.String(30))
 Email = db.Column(db.String(30))
 Pass = db.Column(db.String(30))
 Phone = db.Column(db.Integer)
 Department = db.Column(db.String(30))
 Major = db.Column(db.String(30))
 meeting = db.relationship('Meeting', backref='creator')
 meetingroom = db.relationship('MeetingRoom', backref='reserver')

    def _init_(self, name, Email, Pass, Phone, Department, Major):
  self.name = name
  self.Email = Email
  self.Pass = Pass
  self.Phone = Phone
  self.Department = Department
  self.Major = Major

class MeetingRoom (db.Model):
 mrid = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
 reserver_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
 #meetingm = db.relationship('Meeting', backref='roomno')
 mid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meeting.Mid'))

class Meeting (db.Model):
 Mid = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
 Mname = db.Column(db.String(100))
 Des = db.Column(db.String(100))
 Date = db.Column(db.String(20))
 creator_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
 meetingroomm = db.relationship('MeetingRoom', backref='mroom')
 #roomno_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meetingroom.mrid')


##json 
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def getuser():
 users = User.query.all()
 output = []
 for user in users:
  user_data = {}
  user_data['id'] = user.id
  user_data['name'] = user.name
  user_data['Email'] = user.Email
  user_data['Pass'] = user.Pass
  user_data['Phone'] = user.Phone
  user_data['Department'] = user.Department
  user_data['Major'] = user.Major
  output.append(user_data)
 return jsonify({'users' : output})


#User_schema
class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
 class Mata:
  fields = ('id', 'name', 'Email', 'Pass', 'Phone', 'Department', 'Major')

#init_schema
user_schema = UserSchema()
users_schema = UserSchema(many=True)

#create user
@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_User():
 #id = request.json['id']
 name = request.json['name']
 Email = request.json['Email']
 Pass = request.json['Pass']
 #Phone = request.json['Phone']
 Department = request.json['Department']
 Major = request.json['Major']

 new_user = User(name, Email, Pass, Department, Major)
 db.session.add(new_user)
 db.session.commit()

 return user_schema.jsonify(new_user)

#meeting_schema
class MeetingSchema(ma.Schema):
 class Mata:
  fields = ('Mid', 'Mname', 'Des', 'Date', 'creator_id')

#init_schema
meeting_schema = MeetingSchema()
meetings_schema = MeetingSchema(many=True)

#create meeting
@app.route('/meeting', methods=['POST'])
def add_meeting():
 Mname = request.json['Mname']
 Des = request.json['Des']
 Date = request.json['Date']


 new_meeting = Meeting(Mname, Des, Date)
 db.session.add(new_meeting)
 db.session.commit()

 return user_schema.jsonify(new_meeting)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

[2nd EDIT: the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxvD6.jpg)

after adding def error:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (name, "Email", "Pass", "Phone", "Department", "Major") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('User 1', 'User1@.com', 'qq1', '0551', 'IT 1', 'IT 1')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Can u please mention the entire code from importing flask upto app.run.

Comment: @DineshSakthivel i added the full code, i followed this tutorial to write the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxGBoY5iNXY&t=357s

Comment: is this field required or not which u have commented? #Phone = request.json['Phone'] since you are passing the params from postman to the request

Comment: it used to give me an issue for the phone but turned out the problem was in the request in postman i thought integer values don't need double quotes, either way i tried adding it back to the code and it still gives me the same error, i think the problem is in the server or postman not the code

Comment: do one thing host the url using ngrok not in your local machine so it will act as a public url then share the URL we will also try passing the same params to the request and will see what the error actually is

Comment: This is the URL: https://0fb4aace.ngrok.io
@DineshSakthivel

Comment: When the postman shows 500 error there must be something pirnted on console as well. Please edit your question and add that as well

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation i added the console log as a screenshot please check the image attached, if that is not what you meant by console please can you elaborate

Comment: @monmon I think you're accessing the route "/users" which is the GET method but actually "/user" is the one you have to call please ensure this

Comment: @monmon i meant python console from where you ran the script.

Comment: @DineshSakthivel i did check and just to make sure i changed the route to "/postuser" and it still gives the same problem

Comment: "Tunnel 0fb4aace.ngrok.io not found"  did you up the server?

Comment: @TechatTheSparksFoundation please check the second edit this is where i ran python

Comment: @DineshSakthivel try this url : https://bf9d67bd.ngrok.io

Comment: it seems to be there is some minor issues in creating classes and passing arguments in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in console the problem is that you are initializing a `User` object using constructor but in `User` class you have not defined any constructor.

Define a constructor like this

```
class User(db.Model): ... 
....
   def __init__(self, username, email):
      self.username = username
      self.email = email
      # all your attributes
```

Comment: Sadly it still gives the same Error

Comment: Have you modified the constructor according to your code. Can you update the code and add the new error screen shot in the question?

Comment: i updated the question, it seems the insert in sql is the problem, how can i fix this?
it shows the name with no quotations

Comment: Drop your previous database and create again.

Comment: Thank you i think it worked, i have a question tho, when i write the post should i add the foreign key to the parameters?

Comment: Yeap you need to add foreign key params as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the Error is due to the Flask's old version, So try resolving it by upgrading your Flask version.

Open Anaconda Prompt and type

```
pip install --upgrade Flask
```

Then restart your IDE